# How to change one of the fields in all tables in the database to a new value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to update a values of the field in all tables in the database.

For example:

I have 4 tables that they all contain 'price' fields.

old

```
tbl_a | tbl_b | tbl_c | tbl_d
price | price | price | price  
 5    |  5    |   6   |   9
 6    |  6    |   7   |   10
```

update '6' to '11'.Then

new

```
tbl_a | tbl_b | tbl_c | tbl_d
price | price | price | price  
 5    |  5    |  11   |   9
 11   |  11   |   7   |   10
```

How can I write this sql?

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using `Oracle` , `MY SQL` , `SQL Server`?

Comment: i am using Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Write four `update` statement:

```
update tbl_a
    set price = 11
    where price = 6;

update tbl_b
    set price = 11
    where price = 6;

update tbl_c
    set price = 11
    where price = 6;

update tbl_d
    set price = 11
    where price = 6;
```

Although MySQL allows multi-table updates, there is no need for that mechanism.  If you want all of these to take effect at the same time, you can write the `update`s in a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html).